# Themosis doesn't run on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I've installed Themosis and trying to config. to work on a local environment.

Following the super simple [instalation guide](http://framework.themosis.com/docs/environment/), I've:

#### Set environment vars

In the root file `.env.local.php`, I've set:

```
return [
    'DB_NAME'       => 'themosis',
    'DB_USER'       => 'root',
    'DB_PASSWORD'   => '',
    'DB_HOST'       => 'localhost',
    'WP_HOME'       => 'http://my-website.dev',
    'WP_SITEURL'    => 'http://my-website.dev/cms'
];
```

#### Identify my local environment

On Windows cmd, I've runned hostname, and it is `Puesto5`

[image]

So, with that info, I've set `environment.php` to:

```
return [
    'local'         => 'Puesto5',
    'production'    => 'your-production-hostname'
];
```

Whit this, I should be able to use `http://my-website.dev` or `http://my-website.dev/cms` as the path to the webpage to start installation but web browser is always trying to redirect me to internet.

If I access to localhost/themosis/htdocs I'm also redirected to `http://dev.my-website/cms/wp-admin/install.php` but I take the same error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` which I think is a www error, not a localhost error.

I'm using XAMPP as server

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct.

The URL you need to visit in order to install WordPress is the one defined at the `WP_HOME` constant: http://my-website.dev

If you visit that URL inside your browser and that this domain is looking over the internet, it means there is no local **virtual host** defined. First, look at the xampp documentation on how to define a virtualhost. Generally you have to define it inside a file called **httpd-vhosts.conf** inside a xampp apache conf directory. Also, oftenly, you need to include this file into your apache main configuration. Look at the following lines inside the **httpd.conf** file:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include c:/xampp2/conf/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and remove the `#` character in front of the `Include` statement in order to load the virtual hosts you're going to define.

Define your virtualhost inside your **httpd-vhosts.conf** file. Here is an example of a virtualhost based on your code above:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp2/htdocs/themosis/htdocs
    ServerName my-website.dev
    <Directory "c:/xampp2/htdocs/themosis/htdocs">
        Options FollowSymlinks Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, you'll need to tell your computer to locally look after this virtualhost by adding it to the `hosts` file. This file in Windows is generally located at this path: `c:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

Add your local domain to it like so (ipv4): `127.0.0.1 my-website.dev`

Now restart xampp. It will reload its Apache server and MySQL server as well. Visit the `my-website.dev` URL inside your browser and it should be working and show the WordPress installation screen.

**Note:** By default your local environment is configured to show all errors. WordPress has a core bug if you try to use a language different than english that triggers an error. If you need another language than the default english, open your `config/environments/local.php` file and set the constant `THEMOSIS_ERROR_REPORT` value to `0`. Complete the WordPress installation then set back the constant value to `-1` for your development.

Hope this helps, let me know how it goes!